# RadTileViewItem Drag/Drop in minimized state

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, telerik, tiles

I am using `RadTileView` in my project, and by default the `Tile` Drag and Drop is enabled when they are in restored state

[image: as in figure 1],

but I can't achieve the same functionality when 1 tile is in maximized state and all others are in minimized state

[image: as in figure 2],

I think that Telerik hasn't provided this functionality in their `RadTileView` control. What would be the best way to achieve this, or is it possible or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching through different blogs, I came to know that this functionality is not available in Telerik Tile view out of the box, but they have added it in their wish list, You can vote for this feature here http://www.telerik.com/support/pits.aspx#/public/silverlight/2449

However as a work arround I have implemented a Behavior my self for RadTileView, which will do the required task.

```
public class RadTilesDragDropBehavior : Behavior<RadTileView>
{
    private RadTileViewItem draggingTile { get; set; }

    public TileViewDragDropBehavior()
    {
        // Insert code required on object creation below this point.
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        // Insert code that you would want run when the Behavior is attached to an object.
        DragDropManager.AddDragInitializeHandler(AssociatedObject, OnDragInitialize);
        DragDropManager.AddDragDropCompletedHandler(AssociatedObject, OnDragAndDropCompleted);
        AssociatedObject.PreviewDragOver += MyTileView_PreviewDragOver;
    }
    private void OnDragInitialize(object sender, DragInitializeEventArgs args)
    {
        var tileView = sender as RadTileView;
        var tileViewItem = args.OriginalSource as RadTileViewItem;

        Point pt = Util.CorrectGetPosition((RadTileView)sender);
        HitTestResult result = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(AssociatedObject, pt);
        if (result != null)
        {
            DependencyObject obj = result.VisualHit.ParentOfType<RadFluidContentControl>();
            if (obj != null)
            {
                //trying to drag from Tile content area, not allowed.
                return;
            }
        }

        if (tileViewItem != null && tileView != null && tileView.MaximizedItem != null)
        {
            args.Data = tileViewItem;
            var draggingImage = new Image
            {
                Source = new Telerik.Windows.Media.Imaging.RadBitmap(tileViewItem).Bitmap,
                Width = tileViewItem.RestoredWidth,
                Height = tileViewItem.RestoredHeight
            };

            if (tileView.MaximizedItem == tileViewItem)
            {
                args.DragVisualOffset = new Point(args.RelativeStartPoint.X - 50, args.RelativeStartPoint.Y-55);
            }
            args.DragVisual = draggingImage;
            tileViewItem.Opacity = 0;
            args.AllowedEffects = DragDropEffects.Move;
            args.Handled = true;
            // keep a copy of dragging tile
            draggingTile = tileViewItem;
        }
    }

    private void OnDragAndDropCompleted(object sender, DragDropCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.OriginalSource.GetType() == typeof(RadTileViewItem))
        {
            if (AssociatedObject.MaximizedItem != null)
            {
                Point pt = Util.CorrectGetPosition((RadTileView)sender);
                HitTestResult result = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(AssociatedObject, pt);
                if (result != null)
                {
                    DependencyObject obj = result.VisualHit.ParentOfType<RadTileViewItem>();
                    if (obj != null)
                    {
                        ((RadTileViewItem)obj).Position = draggingTile.Position;
                        draggingTile.Opacity = 100;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        draggingTile.Opacity = 100;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    draggingTile.Opacity = 100;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private void MyTileView_PreviewDragOver(object sender, System.Windows.DragEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement container = sender as FrameworkElement;
        if (AssociatedObject.MaximizedItem != null)
        {
            if (container == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            double tolerance = 60;
            double verticalPos = Util.CorrectGetPosition((RadTileView)container).Y;
            double offset = 20;
            ScrollViewer scrollViewer = AssociatedObject.FindChildByType<ScrollViewer>();

            if (verticalPos < tolerance) // Top of visible list?             
            {
                scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollViewer.VerticalOffset - offset); //Scroll up.             
            }
            else if (verticalPos > container.ActualHeight - tolerance) //Bottom of visible list?             
            {
                scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollViewer.VerticalOffset + offset); //Scroll down.                 
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        // Insert code that you would want run when the Behavior is removed from an object.
        DragDropManager.RemoveDragInitializeHandler(AssociatedObject, OnDragInitialize);
        DragDropManager.RemoveDragDropCompletedHandler(AssociatedObject, OnDragAndDropCompleted);
        AssociatedObject.PreviewDragOver -= MyTileView_PreviewDragOver;
    }

}



public static class Util
{
    public static Point CorrectGetPosition(Visual relativeTo)
    {
        Win32Point w32Mouse = new Win32Point();
        GetCursorPos(ref w32Mouse);
        return relativeTo.PointFromScreen(new Point(w32Mouse.X, w32Mouse.Y));
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct Win32Point
    {
        public Int32 X;
        public Int32 Y;
    };

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool GetCursorPos(ref Win32Point pt);
};
```

XAML would be like this

```
<telerik:RadTileView  x:Name="MyTileView" ItemsSource={Binding TileItems}>
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <behaviors:RadTilesDragDropBehavior/>
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</telerik:RadTileView>
```